# passing parameter in sql server script file in java

Tags: java, sql-server, filereader

I have sql files in my pc:

Example: `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Queries\test.sql`

Query in `test.sql` example :

```
Select * from table where colname like '%me%';
```

I am running this in a java program like this:

```
FileReader SomeName = new FileReader("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Queries\test.sql");
ResultSet rsjs = null;
rsjs = jsscript.runScript(myconn, SomeName);
```

This is working fine, but now I need a way to pass parameter in this sql file so that the query will be like:

```
Select * from table where colname like @parameter;
```

Is it possible?

PS: I cannot use query directly in java program. I know how to pass the parameter in query but this question is related to pass parameter in sql file. store procedure is also out of option.

Comment: you might consider using store procedure instead

Comment: Thanks Tuyen, but store proc is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `StrSubstitutor` https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrSubstitutor.html.

The sql string can have variables as:

```
String query = "Select * from table where colname like ${parameter};"
```

Then create a map like:

```
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("parameter", "%me%");
```

Now you can replace the variables using:

```
StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(values);
return sub.replace(query);
```

Edit 1:
If the query is coming from a file, you can read the file and store it in a string. Look into `Files.readAllLines(path, charset)`